Get the dimensions of a unit of 3D Models
I'm working on an AR Project using Unity3D. In Unity 1 unit equates to 1m in real life. So a cube that'ss 1,1,1 is exactly 1m², in my AR application.
Now if I import 3D models from various sources, like Blender or Cinema4D, the units of these 3D models may not apply to this scale. Sometimes a unit is 1km sometomes 1inch etc etc.
Is there a way to unify the dimensions 3D models, so 1 unit will always be scaled correctly in unity? I don't want to import an object into a 3D-Editor, to adjust it, I want to do this inside Unity.The idea is, I'm loading in a 3D Model. A method is telling me, how much this 3D model needs to be scaled to fit into unitys unit diemensions.
If a unit of 3D model is 1km, the resulting multiplyer should result 0.001

In the glTF format, 1 unit = 1 meter. Other file formats may or may not specify units. Regardless of what the file format requires, unfortunately, 3D models from "various sources" may or may not have been exported to any particular scale.

I can't confirm that. The units of a gltf/glb files are defined by the exporter.

glTF 2.0, Section 3.4, Coordinate System and Units. But, unfortunately, there's no guarantee that a particular exporter respects the required units.

In Unity there is an option to specify the "Scale Factor" of the imported model in the asset's import settings.
Modifying this value should achieve what you want without needing to use a separate "3D-Editor".

